# Trying to create a PHP function that only utilizes new instance of variable

Tags: php, html

I am trying to teach myself PHP. I have looked to find out how to make this work.

I have an online portfolio that I am posting my weekly school assignments and their grades when I receive them.

I currently have something that looks like this:

```
<?php
$page_title = "MATH203 | Journey to my Oasis";
$grade = "A = 185/185";
$course_title = "Applications of Discrete Mathematics";
$course_description = "Math. A fun four letter word. A lot of people have issues with this subject. I like math. I am not proficient by any stretch of the imagination, but I like it. It is challenging. Having this course after programming, I believe, will allow me to think of it in the manner in which it is intended. The professor is also teaches computer science. This should be interesting.";
?>

<?php include("../includes/header.php");?>
<?php include("../includes/navigation.php");?>
<?php include("../includes/classannounce.php");?>

<div id="content">
    <div id="content_container">
        <div class="one_half">
            <h3>Discussion Board Posts</h3>
            <h4><ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="url" target="_blank">Week 1</a>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; Grade - A
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="url" target="_blank">Week 2</a>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; Not yet graded
                </li>
                <!--
                    <li>
                    <a href="url" target="_blank">Week 3</a>
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; Grade - A
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="url" target="_blank">Week 5</a>
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; Grade - B-
                    </li>
                -->
                <li>All links open a new window</li>
            </ul></h4>
        </div>
    </div><!--end content_container-->
</div><!--end content-->
'<?php include("../includes/footer.php");?>
</body>
```

What I would like to do is have a separate PHP file that I include in the header PHP file so it goes everywhere with me just to cut down on the amount of code.

Currently what I am doing is just hiding the html for the weeks that I haven't come up to yet. I am using the original page as a template and just changing it as I go. I am trying to incorporate PHP more so that I can make changes easier and so that I can try to learn as much as I can. I figure that by calling a function an populating it with the variables needed I can cut down on the code needed and time required.

This separate file would have a function like:

```
<?php
function assignment()
{
    $skydoc = '';
    $week_no = '';
    $grade_letter = '';
    echo '<li><a href="', $skydoc, '" target="_blank">Week ', $week_no,
        '</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; Grade - ', $grade_letter, '</li>';
}
?>
```

I try calling the function an include the variables in it so that it will fill in the appropriate sections.

```
assignment($skydoc = 'url', $week_no = '2', $grade_letter = '?')
```

I try that in the same file for testing purposes but all I get in HTML when I try it on my server is this

```
<li>
    <a href="" target="_blank">Week </a>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; Grade - 
</li>
```

Thank you in advance. Any more questions or need clarification, please let me know.

Comment: If you wanted to get really fancy, you could try having fun figuring out multi-dimensional arrays. Basically, your array would start like `$weeks[1] = array( "grade" => "A", "skydoc" => "url");` where the `1` is the week number. As the weeks go on, you simply add another array to `$weeks` and have the table auto-generate based on how many array elements there are. I'm not saying your way is bad, I'm just trying to give you another idea to play with since you said you were doing this to learn.

Comment: The multidimensional array idea seems pretty cool. I will look into this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your calling the function a bit incorrectly. function declaration should have the place holders for the variables you are passing into it.

```
 function assignment($skydoc = 'url', $week_no = '2', $grade_letter = '?')
 {
            echo '<li>
                <a href="',$skydoc,'" target="_blank">Week ',$week_no,'</a>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; Grade - ',$grade_letter,'
              </li>';
 }
```

Then when you want to call the function you simply invoke the following

```
assignment('value', 1, 'A');
```

if you call assignment as follows then the default values you have placed in the variables will be assinged.

```
assignment(); // url, 2, ?
```

Answer (score 1):

close...

```
function assignment($skydoc = '', $week_no = '', $grade_letter = ''){
    echo '<li>
                <a href="'.$skydoc.'" target="_blank">Week '.$week_no.'</a>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; Grade - '.$grade_letter.'
              </li>';
}

assignment('url', '2', '?');
```